# CMake set_property command with generator expressions using multiple values

Tags: visual-studio, build, cmake, cmake-language

I am using CMake v3.13.4 with the `Visual Studio 2017 Win64` generator and I need to modify the command line options for the Visual Studio Librarian (for a CMake object library).

To achieve that CMake offers the target property [`STATIC_LIBRARY_OPTIONS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/prop_tgt/STATIC_LIBRARY_OPTIONS.html) that can be set by the [`set_property`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/command/set_property.html) and `set_target_properties` command.

The documentation states that `STATIC_LIBRARY_OPTIONS` supports generator expressions:

> Contents of `STATIC_LIBRARY_OPTIONS` may use “generator expressions” with the
>   syntax `$<...>`. See the [cmake-generator-expressions(7)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#manual:cmake-generator-expressions(7))
>   manual for available expressions. See the [cmake-buildsystem(7)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#manual:cmake-buildsystem(7))
>   manual for more on defining buildsystem properties.

**But:** No matter what I try, the values are not properly escaped´, e.g.

```
set_property(TARGET object_library PROPERTY STATIC_LIBRARY_OPTIONS $<$<CONFIG:Release>:/WX /NOLOGO /LTCG /ERRORREPORT:NONE>)
```

leads to the following in Visual Studio:

```
All Options: `/OUT:"..." /LTCG /MACHINE:X64 /NOLOGO 
Additional Options: %(AdditionalOptions) /machine:x64 ""$"<1:/WX" "/ERRORREPORT:NONE>"
```

I've tried the following, all of them seem to fail.

```
set_property(TARGET object_library PROPERTY
  STATIC_LIBRARY_OPTIONS $<$<CONFIG:Release>:/WX /NOLOGO /LTCG /ERRORREPORT:NONE>
  #STATIC_LIBRARY_OPTIONS "$<$<CONFIG:Release>:/WX /NOLOGO /LTCG /ERRORREPORT:NONE>"
  #STATIC_LIBRARY_OPTIONS $<$<CONFIG:Release>:"/WX /NOLOGO /LTCG /ERRORREPORT:NONE">
  #STATIC_LIBRARY_OPTIONS $<$<CONFIG:Release>:/WX /NOLOGO /LTCG /ERRORREPORT:NONE>
  #STATIC_LIBRARY_OPTIONS $<$<CONFIG:Release>:/WX;/NOLOGO;/LTCG;/ERRORREPORT:NONE>
  #STATIC_LIBRARY_OPTIONS $<$<CONFIG:Release>:"/WX;/NOLOGO;/LTCG;/ERRORREPORT:NONE">
  #STATIC_LIBRARY_OPTIONS "$<$<CONFIG:Release>:/WX;/NOLOGO;/LTCG;/ERRORREPORT:NONE>"
  )
```

So my question is: How can I pass multiple values using generator expressions to `STATIC_LIBRARY_OPTIONS` with the `set_property` or `set_target_properties` command?

Comment: "How can I pass multiple values using generator expressions?" - **Wrap each value** into its own generator expression: `$<$<CONFIG:Release>:/WX> $<$<CONFIG:Release>:/NOLOGO> ...`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @Tsyvarev, I've been able to solve this problem. The solution is to **wrap each value** into its own generator expression:

```
set_property(TARGET object_library PROPERTY
    STATIC_LIBRARY_OPTIONS
      $<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:/WX>
      $<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:/NOLOGO>
      $<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:/ERRORREPORT:NONE>
      $<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:$<$<CONFIG:Release>:/LTCG>>
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a **list** of options:

```
set(option_list /WX /NOLOGO /LTCG /ERRORREPORT:NONE)
```

you may create a list of generator expressions for them by a single command:

```
list(TRANSFORM option_list
  REPLACE ".+" "$<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:\\0>"
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE option_list_msvc
)
```

Resulted list can be used directly:

```
set_property(TARGET object_library PROPERTY STATIC_LIBRARY_OPTIONS ${option_list_msvc})
```

Command flow [list(TRANSFORM)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.19/command/list.html#transform) is available since CMake 3.12.

Answer (score 0):

Below you find my answer, which, as @Tsyvarev helped me realize, **doesn't help in the question's situation**. Please instead consider his answer.
As I found his comments below helpful, I'll leave the answer here, so that you may read the comments.

This answer is for future readers with newer cmake:
As detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65043369/10978334) by @firmament, depending on the cmake version, it may also be possible to put all values into a list via

```
set(my_option_list /WX /NOLOGO /LTCG /ERRORREPORT:NONE)
```

and pass this list to the generator expression:

```
"<$<CONFIG:Release>:${my_option_list}>"
```

This works on cmake 3.18.4 with clang and gcc generator expressions.

Comment: I have tested this approach. Your generator expression in `Release` configuration internally produces `"/WX;/NOLOGO;/LTCG;/ERRORREPORT:NONE"`. For some commands this is equivalent to the list of those options: `/WX /NOLOGO /LTCG /ERRORREPORT:NONE`, so everything works. Among these command is `add_compile_options` from [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65035750/3440745). But for some other commands this doesn't work. E.g. `add_custom_target(my_target COMMAND echo "<$<CONFIG:Release>:${my_option_list}>"` prints semicolons between the options. (Instead of printing them space-separated).

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! I guess, that invalidates my answer to this question. What's the best course of action? Should I delete it? Apparently it is not a right answer to this question.

Comment: "Apparently it is not a right answer to this question." - Why do you think so? You answer answers the current question, it answers your question. Actually, it resolves `add_custom_target` problem, but with additional COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS keyword: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65231456/3440745. I have just explained some... specialties of your approach. BTW, I have upvoted your answer, not downvoted.

Comment: What I meant, is, that using just my answer doesn't lead to the desired outcome and so future readers would not benefit from it.
I think, I should delete it to not confuse people that would better use your answer.
As I'm not well versed with SO, I'll wait for a comment from you, whether this would be foolish or not.

Comment: Also maybe the current behaviour should be filed as a bug?
I for one find it extremely confusing, how generator expressions work so differently for different commands.
But I don't feel confident in my abilities and lack thereof with cmake to actually file one.

Comment: "how generator expressions work so differently for different commands." - No, the generator expressions *themselves* works in the same way. And you generator 
expression **always** produces `"/WX;/NOLOGO;/LTCG;/ERRORREPORT:NONE"`. But such **semicolon-separated string** is treated differently by different commands. It seems that many commands (which support generator expressions) treat that string as **list**, and this is the desired behavior. Command `add_custom_target` treats it differently... but there is an **official** way for change that behavior. I see no problem in that.

Comment: I think your comments might be helpful, therefor I will not delete my answer, so that they remain. I'll update it to direct everyone to your answer.