# Cmake Generator expressions with multiple entries (spaces?)

Tags: c++, cmake, generator-expression

(During writing this question I found a solution, so this just documents it, because I would really have needed it beforehand!)

Im writing a c++ project and use cmake for it.

In my cmake file I have:

```
set(MY_DEBUG_WARNINGS "-Og -Wall"
)

# Add warnings:
add_compile_options("$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:${MY_DEBUG_WARNINGS}>"
"$<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:Clang,AppleClang>:-fcolor-diagnostics>"
"$<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:GNU>:-fdiagnostics-color>"
)
```

which doesn't work, because the compile command picks up extra escaped quotes:

```
  "/usr/bin/clang++ -I../src/Exception/include -g \"-Og -Wall\" -fcolor-diagnostics - 
  std=c++17 -o src/Exception/CMakeFiles/exception.dir/Exception.cpp.o -c 
  /home/bob/app/src/Exception/Exception.cpp",
  "file": "/home/bob/app/src/Exception/Exception.cpp"
```

The problem seems to be the space in the warnings.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55262774/10978334) "solves" the issue by wrapping each value in its own expression, which seems weird and awfully impractical.
Is there any easier way to pass a string with spaces in it in a generator expression?

As mentioned I found an acceptable solution myself but will not yet mark it as my accepted answer because I'm not sure, this is a good solution and not a hack that may bite me if I ever need semi-colons in the options themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"-Og -Wall"` is a string, whereas `"-Og;-Wall"` is a list (as lists are semicolon separated strings).

So `set(my_list -Og -Wall)` (no double quotes) also creates a list. Read all about it [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/list.html).

Comment: Thank you so much! This finally makes sense!
Is it just me or is the cmake documentation not helpful? I almost never understand it, when I try to read it because it almost never contains concrete examples.
But maybe its not written for newbies and more experienced cmake users gain more from it.

Comment: Do you happen to know, why I cannot insert the list directly into the generator expression? Like `$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:-Og -Wall>`
It doesn't work with quotes around it or without.

Comment: Also: I guess this is a better answer for the linked question. Do you want to supply your answer there, too? If not, I will.

Comment: Agree that the docs could benefit _greatly_ from a few examples :). What I normally do is I search github for things, eg "target_compile_definitions language:cmake" to find something concrete.

Comment: For some reason when you use a list in a generator expression the syntax is different, then there's a comma between the elements: `$<$<PLATFORM_ID:Linux,FreeBSD>:${some_variable}>`

Comment: Beware that if you are on an older release, I remember getting bitten by this on at least 3.10, you could not add multiple values to genex as above, then you had to repeat the conditon for each value.

Comment: That sounds like a useful hint, I'll try that (searching for examples on github) next time.
For your other comment: I meant, that I cannot replace `${some_variable}` with the list itself. Or rather I can but then have to use semi-colon instead of space. But well, suits me fine, using a variable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is indeed the space and it can be solved like this:

```
 set(MY_DEBUG_WARNINGS "-Og;-Wall"
 )
```

replacing all spaces with a semi-colon. With this the compile command becomes:

```
 "/usr/bin/clang++ -I../src/Exception/include -g -Og -Wall 
 -fcolor-diagnostics -std=c++17 -o 
 src/Exception/CMakeFiles/exception.dir/Exception.cpp.o -c 
 /home/bob/app/src/Exception/Exception.cpp",
```

which actually works.

I have no idea whether this makes problems elsewhere, so a comment from someone with more knowledge would be much appreciated.