# Configuration-specific add_custom_command with Xcode generator

Tags: c++, xcode, cmake

I want to create a custom command that will merge all static libraries into a fat static library using Apple's `libtool` command during build. I'm using Xcode generator and CMake 3.19.1. My script is like this:

```
set( TARGET_OUTPUT_NAME ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/fat-libs/${CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR}/lib${libname}.a )
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT
        ${TARGET_OUTPUT_NAME}
    COMMAND
        /usr/bin/libtool -static -o ${TARGET_OUTPUT_NAME} $<TARGET_FILE:${libname}>
        $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:${all_dependencies_debug}>
        $<$<CONFIG:Release>:${all_dependencies_release}>
    DEPENDS
        ${libname}
    COMMENT
        "Building merged static library"
)
add_custom_target( ${TARGET_NAME} DEPENDS ${TARGET_OUTPUT_NAME} )
```

`libname` is the name of the target whose dependencies for debug and release are collected into `all_dependencies_debug` and `all_dependencies_release` lists and should be merged. The contents of those lists may contain actual paths to static libraries or generator expressions (in case dependency is another target, either real or imported).

However, this generates the following script in Xcode:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
set -e
if test "$CONFIGURATION" = "Debug"; then :
  cd /path/to/build/folder
  /usr/bin/libtool -static -o /path/to/build/folder/fat-libs/$CONFIGURATION$EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME/libMyLib.a /path/to/build/folder/Debug/libMyLib.a $<1:/path/to/first/debug/libSomething.a /path/to/second/debug/libSomething.a> $<0:/path/to/first/release/libSomething.a /path/to/second/release/libSomething.a>
fi
if test "$CONFIGURATION" = "Release"; then :
  cd /path/to/build/folder
  /usr/bin/libtool -static -o /path/to/build/folder/fat-libs/$CONFIGURATION$EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME/libMyLib.a /path/to/build/folder/Release/libMyLib.a $<0:/path/to/first/debug/libSomething.a /path/to/second/debug/libSomething.a> $<1:/path/to/first/release/libSomething.a /path/to/second/release/libSomething.a>
fi
```

This, of course, fails during build because xcode throws `syntax error` when parsing `$<1:`.

I've also tried adding `VERBATIM`, but this only causes `$` to be escaped.

Is this a bug in CMake Xcode generator or did I do something wrong?

I've also tried using older versions of CMake (3.18.4), which don't support Modern Apple Build System, but to no avail.

[CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.19/command/add_custom_command.html) states that `COMMAND` part of `add_custom_command` should be able to use generator expressions.

Comment: Actually it **is** possible to use list of items in generator expressions, as I've been told after [asking the same question on CMake gitlab](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/21576). The trick is in using `COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS` - I was just about to add the answer here and close the question, but you were quicker.

Comment: Ok, so your question has some specifics comparing to the other one. I have reopened it.

Comment: Since you know that your problem is not specific to XCode, could you edit the title?

Comment: @Tsyvarev, since the question directly relates to the generated Xcode build phase script, I would prefer keeping the same title. Although, now that I found the answer, I do agree that the original issue is not necessarily related to the CMake Xcode generator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the trick is in using `COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS`.

As explained in [this CMake gitlab issue](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/21576), the correct CMake script is:

```
set( TARGET_OUTPUT_NAME ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/fat-libs/${CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR}/lib${libname}.a )
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT
        ${TARGET_OUTPUT_NAME}
    COMMAND
        /usr/bin/libtool -static -o "${TARGET_OUTPUT_NAME}" "$<TARGET_FILE:${libname}>"
        "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:${all_dependencies_debug}>"
        "$<$<CONFIG:Release>:${all_dependencies_release}>"
    DEPENDS
        ${libname}
    COMMENT
        "Building merged static library"
    VERBATIM
    COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS
)
add_custom_target( ${TARGET_NAME} DEPENDS ${TARGET_OUTPUT_NAME} )
```

First, all parameters must be given in double quotes, in order to ensure that spaces and `;` separator in list are passed through to the `add_custom_command`.
Next, the `COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS` will [make sure](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.19/command/add_custom_command.html) that list given via generator expression (i.e. `"$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:${all_dependencies_debug}>"`) will be properly expanded - without this, the semicolons would end-up in the final Xcode build phase script.
Finally, the `VERBATIM` is needed to properly escape all other characters that may confuse the Xcode phase build script.

Thank you Brad King for your quick help and response at [gitlab issues](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/21576).

Comment: Man, was this helpful. Thank you.