# CMake: target_sources() warning CMP0076

Tags: cmake, cmakelists-options

I have an INTERFACE called exi and I want its INTERFACE_SOURCES to be with the source code directory during build then later during install I would copy the source files elsewhere and set INTERFACE_SOURCES to that install directory

I have the following CMakeList.txt

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.10)
# Specify C sources and HEADER_PUBLIC directories
set(SOURCE_C
    file1.c
    file2.c
)

set(HEADER_PUBLIC
    src/header1.h
    include/header2.h    
)

#set a variable with source code install dir
set(SRC_INSTALL_DIR share/src)

#  Construct List with Full path for the build interface
set(SOURCE_C_BUILD "")
foreach(file ${SOURCE_C})
    list(APPEND SOURCE_C_BUILD "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/${file}")
endforeach()

# Construct List with Full path for the install interface
set(SOURCE_C_INSTALL "")
foreach(file ${SOURCE_C})
    list(APPEND SOURCE_C_INSTALL "${SRC_INSTALL_DIR}/${file}")
endforeach()

# Create an Interface
add_library(exi INTERFACE)

target_sources(exi INTERFACE
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${SOURCE_C_BUILD}>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${SOURCE_C_INSTALL}>
)

target_include_directories(exi INTERFACE
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${SRC_INSTALL_DIR}>
)

# install source code
install(FILES ${SOURCE_C_BUILD} DESTINATION ${SRC_INSTALL_DIR})

# Install Header files
install(FILES ${HEADER_PUBLIC} DESTINATION include)
```

and in a higher level CMakeLists.txt exi is exported with different configs in build than install with these lines

```
install(
    TARGETS exi 
    EXPORT exi_targets
    DESTINATION lib/exi
)

install(EXPORT exi_targets DESTINATION lib/exi FILE exiConfig.cmake)

export(TARGETS exi FILE exiConfig.cmake)
```

### OUTPUT

The output is correct in both exiConfig.cmake files

- build interface exiConfig.cmake

```
# Create imported target exi
add_library(exi INTERFACE IMPORTED)

set_target_properties(exi PROPERTIES
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "/workspaces/Project/inf/exi/include;/workspaces/Project/inf/exi/src"
  INTERFACE_SOURCES "/workspaces/Project/inf/exi/src/file1.c;/workspaces/Project/inf/exi/src/file2.c"
)
```

- install interface exiConfig.cmake

```
# Create imported target exi
add_library(exi INTERFACE IMPORTED)

set_target_properties(exi PROPERTIES
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/include;${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/share/src"
  INTERFACE_SOURCES "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/share/src/file1.c;${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/share/src/file2.c"
)
```

### WARNING

but I am getting this warning

```
  Policy CMP0076 is not set: target_sources() command converts relative paths
  to absolute.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0076" for policy details.  Use
  the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  An interface source of target "exi" has a relative path.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
```

as you can see ${SOURCE_C_BUILD} is not relative path and if I comment the line with ${SOURCE_C_INSTALL} then I would still get the same warning.

Comment: Applying a **generator expression** to a **list** is wrong: instead it should be a **list of generator expressions**, each of which is applied to the single element. E.g. `$<BUILD_INTERFACE:/path/to/file1.c> $<BUILD_INTERFACE:/path/to/file1.2>`. See e.g. [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55262774/cmake-set-property-command-with-generator-expressions-using-multiple-values). The fact that CMake produces "correct" `exiConfig.cmake` is probably related to [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65106793/3440745) (see also my comments to it).

Comment: Funny fact about your code: Would you raise the version in `CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.10)` to 3.12 or more, you will get the **error**: `CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  Target "exi" INTERFACE_SOURCES property contains path:

    "/home/tester/tests/cmake/${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/share/src/file1.c"

  which is prefixed in the source directory.`

It is also originated in using a generator expression to a list.

Comment: @Tsyvarev having a list of generator expressions as you proposed worked without warnings and it still works after raising the version to 3.20 while raising the version with my code would indeed result in the cmake error you mentioned.
Thank you for your help.