# set_property SOURCE COMPILE_FLAGS separates the flags with semicolon instead of space

Tags: c, cmake, makefile, clang

I want to set special flags for a few C files in the folder. I tried to use `set_property`. Below, you can see two variants - once I use a list, once I write the flags directly in the properties:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

file(GLOB_RECURSE all_sources "./*.c" "./*.S")

set(CURRENT_LIB_NAME my_c_library)
enable_language(ASM)
set(c_flags
    -msse4.1
    # some other flags
)

set(c_sandybridge_flags
    -O2
    -march=sandybridge
    -mtune=sandybridge
)
file(GLOB SANDYBRIDGE_SRC_FILES
    "*_slow.c"
    "*_dispatcher.c"
    "arion.c"
)
set_property(SOURCE ${SANDYBRIDGE_SRC_FILES} PROPERTY COMPILE_FLAGS ${c_sandybridge_flags})

file(GLOB HASWELL_SRC_FILES
    "./*_ab2.c"
)
set_property(SOURCE ${HASWELL_SRC_FILES} PROPERTY COMPILE_FLAGS -O2 -mavx2 )

add_compile_options(
    "$<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:C>:${c_flags}>"
)

add_library(${CURRENT_LIB_NAME} STATIC
    ${all_sources}
)

target_include_directories(${CURRENT_LIB_NAME} PRIVATE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/mylibrary/include)
```

In both cases, if I look what make commands are run, I see stuff like this:

```
/usr/bin/clang -Isomeinclude -msse4.1 -O2;-march=sandybridge;-mtune=sandybridge -MD -MT CMakeFiles/c_file.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/c_file.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/c_file.c.o -c lib/c_file.c
```

Essentially, the added options are separated by `;` instead of a space. How can I fix that?

Comment: "Below, you can see two variants - once I use a list, once I write the flags directly in the properties" - But these are not all differences between the variants! The command `add_compile_options` assigns `COMPILE_OPTIONS` property, but with `set_property` command you assign `COMPILE_FLAGS` property. The latter property is [deprecated](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/COMPILE_FLAGS.html) and it is not clear from the documentation whether the property should contain list (semicolon-separated) or string (space-separated items like in `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variable).

Comment: As for the variant with `add_compile_options`, there you use a **generator expression**, where you put a **list**. Most likely exactly that aspect causes the problem: that approach works for some CMake commands, but doesn't work for others. According to [that my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55262774/cmake-set-property-command-with-generator-expressions-using-multiple-values#comment115307976_65106793), `add_compile_options` worked with such approach, but it could be that some new version of CMake breaks it. Correct approach is to wrap every list item into its own genex.